# Different behavior of pointer de-reference

Tags: c, pointers

I was actually trying to make sense of the `container_of()` macro in [Linux](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/tools/include/linux/kernel.h#L25) kernel which involves something like this:

```
#ifndef offsetof
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
#endif

#ifndef container_of
/**
 * container_of - cast a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @ptr:    the pointer to the member.
 * @type:   the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({\
    const typeof(((type *)0)->member) * __mptr = (ptr);\
    (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member)); })
```

I found the expression `(type *)0)->member` niggling. I couldn't understand why this expression worked in these macros. I read up [this](https://www.stupid-projects.com/container_of/) article and then tried coming up with a program to understand it further:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
}group;

int main(){
    group a;
    printf("Address of second is %p, group is %p\n", &a.second, &a);
    size_t offset = &(((group*)0)->second);
    printf("Offset of second is %zd\n", offset );
    printf("Address of group is %p\n", (char*)&a.second - offset);
    int val = ((group*)0)->second;
}
```

I do understand that the expression `(group *)0)->member` is not the `void*` pointer but rather a pointer of `group` type but ultimately isn't it finally a `NULL` address that's being referred? This line works fine

```
size_t offset = &(((group*)0)->second);
```

whereas this results in a `SIGSEGV`

```
int val = ((group*)0)->second;
```

How is memory access different in both cases?

Comment: The macros aren't actually accessing any memory because they're not dereferencing anything. If the base address is zero, the offset is just the member location relative to the start of the struct.

Comment: In the first case you're not dereferencing, you're just calculating the offset by basically computing an address in the second you're dereferencing a pointer to 0.

Comment: NULL is defined as `(void *)0`, not `0` cast to a pointer of non-void type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the compiler already "knows" the offset at the compile time and doesn't need to compute it, therefore no memory access is needed and no segfault occurs. That is why `offsetof` would **not** work with [an opaque struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596168/hiding-struct-members). This becomes particularly clear when you inspect a corresponding `x86_64` assembly code. When I ran `gcc -S` for the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
}group;

int main(){
    group a;
    size_t offset = (size_t) &(((group*)0)->second); # notice the cast to avoid a warning
    return 0;
}
```

there were basically only two instructions corresponding to the meat of my C program:

```
movq    $4, -24(%rbp)       # move literal value 4 to *(rbp-24)
movl    $0, %eax            # move literal value 0 to eax (this is just a part of "return 0;" statement)
```

If I were now to change the last two lines in the C to:

```c
size_t offset = (size_t) &(((group*)0)->third);
return 1;
```

The assembly code would only differ in those two instructions. They would then read:

```
movq    $8, -24(%rbp)   
movl    $1, %eax
```

The 4 and 8 are there because on my machine `int` is equal to 4 bytes. More importantly, it is known what the members of your struct are (that’s why an opaque struct wouldn’t work - this information is hidden.) Since the compiler (or assembler) has this information available from the start it can and it does just "hardcode" it. It doesn't do any dereferencing, because it does not need to.

If I now add the problematic line to my C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
}group;

int main(){
    group a;
    size_t offset = (size_t) &(((group*)0)->third);
    int val = ((group*)0)->second;
    return 0;
}
```

and assemble it, I get the following additional instructions:

```
movl    $0, %eax            # move literal value 0 to eax
movl    4(%rax), %eax       # dereference the value at *(rax + 4) and save it in eax
movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)     # move the value saved at eax to the *(rbp - 28)
```

The first line just stores literal value of 0 in the lower half of the `rax` register (the upper half is [zeroed anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)). Segfault is triggered in the next instruction, when memory is dereferenced at the location `rax + 4 = 4` in an attempt to store the obtained value to the `eax` register. In fact, here you can see again that compiler *just knows* the offset of the `struct group` member `second` by how it simply offsets the location of the struct (saved in `rax`) by a literal value of 4. It just so happens that this is not a valid memory, and hence the OS terminates your program by sending it `SIGSEGV`.

---

As said in the comments, in the first example you're not dereferencing anything, but only calculating an address. In the second case you're actually dereferencing a pointer to 0 which leads to a segfault. It's all there in [the article](https://www.stupid-projects.com/container_of/) you've linked yourself:

> Now that the struct offset is “normalized”, we don’t even care about the size of the green member or the size of the structure because it’s easy the absolute offset is the same with relative offset. This is exactly what &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER does. This code dereferences the struct to the zero offset of the memory.
>
> This generally is not a clever thing to do, but in this case this code is not executed or evaluated. It’s just a trick like the one I’ve shown above with the tape measure. **The *offsetof()* macro will just return the offset of the member compared to zero. It’s just a number and you don’t access this memory**. Therefore, doing this trick the only thing you need to know is the type of the structure.

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So to put it succinctly, it all boils down to whether the compiler evaluates the expression in a regular way or just hardcodes the values based on the architecture-specific information. Is there a way to determine how the compiler treats expressions without resorting to disassembly?

Comment: @Zoso Well, you could tell it's not being dereferenced as there was no segfault. It has this information because it was given with the definition of the struct (the architecture-specific information like the size of an int is only useful if it knows what the struct members are). If by "regular" you mean "literal", I think it's safe to assume that the answer is "no" most of the time, as compilers often optimize the code to at least some degree.

Comment: @Zoso I hate to ask, but why the downvote together with accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to accept the answer and instead I clicked upvote. I just re-clicked on the upvote button and all of a sudden it went down to 0. I can't appear to upvote it again. Really very sorry. Can you add something minor so that I may re-vote on the answer?

Comment: @Zoso no worries, there was space for improvement anyway:)